# How to add an ImageLoader in android

Tags: android, github, universal-image-loader

I have an android game application in which each level has a 250*250(pixel) image and all the levels are in one Activity named "game1.java". because many layout features change in the levels; I call the same class using Intent and finish() the class when I wanna change the level of the game.
in that I have problem in the ram usage and I tried to use this  in the game1 class:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

but I get Unfortunately each time I wanna open the activity.

this is an attribute of the game1 class:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader;
```

this part is at the start of onCreate:

```
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(getBaseContext());
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
            .delayBeforeLoading(0)
            .cacheInMemory(false) // default
            .cacheOnDisk(true) // default
            .build();
```

whenever I need a new image i call this function and give the strName name and extension of my image that is in assets folder. for example "image1.jpg"

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    String imageUri = "assets://" + strName;

    //Bitmap bmp = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(imageUri);
    imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri,new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
            bmp_loader=loadedImage;
        }
    });

    return bmp_loader;
}
```

then I give the image to the ImageView via setImageBitmap function

where is the problem?

Comment: my answer doesn't fix your problem?

Comment: I added my answer to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using my friends' helps; this is what i did eventually to fix the problem:

step 1: I setup my loader in the first activity of my game; in the onCreate:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration
            .Builder(getBaseContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .build();
```

step 2:

in the game1.class ; after super.oncreate:

```
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(getBaseContext());
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
            .delayBeforeLoading(0)
            .cacheInMemory(false) // default
            .cacheOnDisk(true) // default
            .build();
```

I gave the imageaddress that needed to a string

```
   ax_level = "level_01.jpg";
```

defined my imageview

```
ImageView posht_safhe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rook_ax);
```

gave the image to my imageView

```
String pin_url = "assets://"+ax_level;
    DisplayImageOptions option = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(false )

            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(pin_url ,posht_safhe, option, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                      Bitmap loadedImage) {

  //                bitmap = loadedImage;
        }
    });
```

and finally it worked

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple mistake :)
you didn't define imageLoader and the `imageLoader` is null when you try to call `loadImage(...)`!

change your code `ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);` to this

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
```